# bash regex pattern argument

Tags: regex, bash

I need to create script who check argument, the argument is Linux command:

**cat script.sh**

```
 case "$1" in 
     cp|cd|ls ) exec "$0" "$1" ;;
             *) echo "error: not permitted" ;;
 esac
```

i need to add check if the first argument is exression like this :

> [ -s $file ] && echo OK

so i add condition like this:

```
 case "$1" in 
   cp|cd|ls| "[ -s .* ] && echo OK" ) exec "$0" "$1" ;;
    *) echo "error: not permitted" ;;
   esac
```

but it doesn't work, any idea, please

Comment: No single argument has spaces in it. Are you putting the "[ -s $file ] && echo OK" argument in quotations when passing it into the script?

Comment: i use a simple quote, i launch the script like this :  script.sh '[ -s $file ] && echo OK'

Answer (score 0):

You can not place conditions into the 'case' pattern. You can place them into the command part of the case.

```
case "$0" in 
     cp|cd|ls )
         [ -s "$1" ] && exec "$0" "$1"
         echo "Bad parameter" ;;
     *) echo "error: not permitted" ;;
esac
```

Also note about "cd": You can not execute "cd /path" in a sub process.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but i don't want to place condition in case , i want to consider the condition like a string a i want a regex who match this string :
 '[ -s "$fichier" ] && echo OK'

Comment: @alpha.romeo unfortunately, the case statement only works with (static) pattern matching, not with conditions. You can switch to a series if 'if'/'elif' statements. More verbose, and flexible.